# Fatal Exception in SurfaceView when I try to setTranslationX and setTranslationY

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I'm using setTranslationX and setTranslationY in my game to shift my SurfaceView so that my player is always in the center of the screen. The exact methods I used are:

```
mySurfaceView.setTranslationX(-player.getX() + GameActivity.GAME_WIDTH/2);
mySurfaceView.setTranslationY(-player.getY() + GameActivity.GAME_HEIGHT/2);
```

Unfortunately when I try to move my player, I get a fatal exception which reads:

```
07-18 23:27:58.628    3059-3085/com.packname.www.gamename E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2018
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:854)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChildFast(ViewGroup.java:4193)
            at android.view.View.invalidateViewProperty(View.java:10423)
            at android.view.View.setTranslationX(View.java:9743)
            at com.packname.www.gamename.game.PlayState.render(PlayState.java:77)
```

How would I go about solving this exception? I need my player to remain at the center of the screen whenever he moves. Also I can't use canvas.translate(x, y) because that won't change the coordinates my TouchListeners receive which I use to move my player. So if I use canvas.translate(x, y) then my collision rectangles end up being located not where my player is rendered. Hence my need for the mySurfaceView.setTranslateX() and mySurfaceView.setTranslateY() methods.

EDIT: Seems I'm not calling setTranslationX & Y from the correct thread. how would I go about calling setTranslationX & Y from the correct thread? I need to be able to constantly update my surfaceview or at the very least update it when my player moves.

Comment: Post PlayState.java line 77 with some context preferably. Edit: it looks like you're calling setTranslation from a separate thread.

Comment: PlayState.java line 77 contains "myView.setTranslationX(myCam.getX());" where "myCam.getX()" returns "x=-player.getX() + GameActivity.GAME_WIDTH/2;". This setTranslation method is constantly being called in my render method which is in my run() method which is called by a thread I created when I created my surfaceview.

Comment: how would I go about calling setTranslationX from the correct thread? I need to be able to constantly update my surfaceview or at the very least update it when my player moves.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
mySurfaceView.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mySurfaceView.setTranslationX(-player.getX() + GameActivity.GAME_WIDTH/2);
        mySurfaceView.setTranslationY(-player.getY() + GameActivity.GAME_HEIGHT/2);

    }
});
```

See [View.post(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: Another option is to use an android.os.Handler

Comment: getting the error "variable 'mySurfaceView' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final". Issue is that mySurfaceView is just a parameter in my render function. When I change it to final in my class I created in, I get all kinds of errors plus this error doesn't go away. Any way around this issue?

Comment: Change it to final in the parameter list then.

Comment: Did that and it works. Thank you my good sir. Out of curiosity, how does the os.Handler solution work?

Comment: It holds a message queue for the thread that it is created on. Typically you use its sendMessage() methods, but it also has a post() method that could be used the same as above.